# Package officeR : body_add_gg. Function does not work with a ggsurvplot object for file.docx

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, officer

I am currently working on a shiny app. This app generates `ggsurvplot` and I want to export them in a .docx report to avoid screenshots.

When I'm adding the `ggsurvplot` in my report with the function `body_add_gg()` i got this message error : `inherits(value, "gg") is not TRUE`.

I would like to know if I can incorporate `ggsurvplot` objects in my report with officeR or if I should create a classic R `plot`.

I tried to directly change the class of my `ggsurvplot` with `class(p) <- "gg"`. But it's doesn't work(which is pretty obvious). `ggsurvplot` and `ggplot` objects are not exactly made in the same way, so just modifying the class name can't work.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A `ggsruvplot` object is a `list` where the plot of the survival curves is stored as an element named `plot`. Hence, one option which works would be to export this element. If you also want the risk table then one option would be to export it separately.

Using a basic minimal reproducible example.

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)
library(officer)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

gg <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE)

doc <- read_docx()

doc <- body_add_gg(doc, value = gg$plot, style = "centered")

print(doc, target = tempfile(fileext = ".docx"))
```

[image]